# Are partial valued functions closures?

Tags: closures

My understanding is that closures are basically functions (and by that I mean piece of code) using *variables that are bound* to some values.

The partial valuation of a function on the other and is nothing but a new function obtained by another one *binding some of its variables/arguments*.

It seems o me that two concepts are basically the same: indeed one could regard (i.e. implement) closures as partial valuations of functions, that use additional arguments for the variables to be bound in the closure, and on the other hand a partial valuation seems to be just the closure of a function in which some of its variables-arguments are bound to values.

Is this line of thought correct? Are these two concepts really the same? And if no, what are the differences between these concepts?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say they are the same thing. They are two concepts that have the same power, but that does not mean they are the same thing.

Comment: Ok, but could you elaborate a little bit more on what are their differences?